# Passing Warning response header in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

Tomcat 8_32

Windows 7

Java 8_51

RestEasy 3.0.11.Final

GWT 2.7.0 (Jetty jetty-9.3.5.v20151012)

Servlet code makes a RestEasy call to another servlet (same container) - second servlet sets the 'Warning' HTTP header on response.  Would like to access that in first servlet but when running in Tomcat, that header is not included.

Code to get header in first servlet:

Object headers = ((ClientResponseFailure) e).getResponse().getResponseHeaders().get("Warning");

Also tried: getHeaders(), getStringHeaders(), and getHeaderString().

When running GWT in superdev mode in IntelliJ (15.0.4) using Jetty, the above returns a List with one item that contains the warning string.  When remote debugging Tomcat, that call returns null.

Added this to web app xml, and also tried Tomcat conf/web.xml...

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Warning</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also tried cors.allowed.headers.

Any pointers?

Comment: What does the response look like in Fiddler [or the proxy of your choice]? Do you see the header there?

Comment: Good idea - but I can't get Fiddler to show me response headers until everything's done (this is all within same container). I did notice that after I set Content-Length and Warning, the response headers still only contain Set-Cookie and X-Frame-Options. When it gets to the second servlet, it has Content-Length, Date, Server, Set-Cookie, and X-Frame-Options. As mentioned, on Jetty everything works fine (ie. I get all headers).

Comment: Got it...didn't realize it wasn't going "over the wire".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems to be a difference between Tomcat and Jetty on when the response is committed.  If I order things as... setStatus, setHeader, getWriter - then it works on both.

I had the getWriter before the set Warning header but the response had already been committed at that point and so no headers could be added.  For some reason this is fine by Jetty.